# Socket Programming - A connection attempt failed Exception

Tags: c#, sockets

Am new to socket programming and am creating a chat application.As like other applications whenever i press enter in a chat window it should send the chat to a particular user.Am maintaining a DB for all users along with their IPAddresses.So whenever i select a user for sending chat it should send to the corresponding IPAddress.As of now am trying to send chat to my own machine(so i hard coded the IPAddress of my machine).But am getting an exception when i try to send my code to my IPAddress.Can anyone please help me out.

My code for socket programming is this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Ping
{
    class SocketProgramming
    {
        //Socket m_socWorker;
        public AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack;
        public Socket m_socListener;
        public Socket m_socWorker;

        public void sendChat(IPAddress toMessengerIP)
        {
            try
            {
                //create a new client socket ...

                m_socWorker = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                String szIPSelected = toMessengerIP.ToString();
                String szPort = "7777";
                int alPort = System.Convert.ToInt16(szPort, 10);

                System.Net.IPAddress remoteIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(szIPSelected);
                System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, alPort);
        //        receive();
                m_socWorker.Connect(remoteEndPoint);

                //Send data
                Object objData =(object)"hi dhivi";
                byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());
                m_socWorker.Send(byData);


            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException se)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
                Console.Out.Write(se.Message);
            }
        }

        public void receive()
        {
            try
            {
                //create the listening socket...
                m_socListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7777);
                //bind to local IP Address...
                m_socListener.Bind(ipLocal);
                //start listening...
                m_socListener.Listen(4);
                // create the call back for any client connections...
                m_socListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
                //cmdListen.Enabled = false;

            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.Out.Write(se.Message);
            }
        }

        public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {
                m_socWorker = m_socListener.EndAccept(asyn);

                WaitForData(m_socWorker);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.Out.Write(se.Message);
            }

        }

        public class CSocketPacket
        {
            public System.Net.Sockets.Socket thisSocket;
            public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1];
        }

        public void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
        {
            try
            {
                //if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
                //{
                //    pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
                //}
                CSocketPacket theSocPkt = new CSocketPacket();
                theSocPkt.thisSocket = soc;
                // now start to listen for any data...
                soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, pfnWorkerCallBack, theSocPkt);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.Out.Write(se.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And whenever the users clicks the enter button it should call the sendChat() method.

private void txt_Userinput_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

```
    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    TabItem tb = (TabItem)this.Parent;
    string user = tb.Header.ToString();
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        richtxtbox_chatwindow.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + user + " : " + txt_Userinput.Text);
        DBCoding dbObject = new DBCoding();
        SocketProgramming socketObj = new SocketProgramming();                
        socketObj.sendChat(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.15.41"));              
    }
    else { return; }
}
```

To get ipaddress of the user

```
public IPAddress getIP()
    {
        String direction = "";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            direction = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //Search for the ip in the html
        int first = direction.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
        int last = direction.LastIndexOf("</body>");
        direction = direction.Substring(first, last - first);
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(direction);
        return ip;
    }
```

Comment: not an answer, a question.
what's the exception? ECONNREFUSED ? or something like that? post the error code and the message

Comment: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.15.41:7777.This is the error message i got

Comment: @Marteen can you pls help me

Comment: Do you get the same result if you try to connect to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Also, just to check - I assume you are calling `receive` at some point?

Comment: No am not getting any error.What is this IpAddress.Also as per my expectation once i send a chat i should be receiving it also right.Am i missing anything in my code ?

Comment: Yes,Am just trying to receive the chat that am sending.It is possible know ?

Comment: What I mean is - are you actually calling `receive` somewhere?

Comment: No am not calling receive.Am expecting the program to respond automatically once it receives a chat

Comment: Well then there's your problem. If there is no one listening at that port, you obviously won't be able to connect.

Comment: But should i do it every time ? then how the application knows that there is an incoming message ?

Comment: You should/could begin listening for connections right when the application starts. No one will be able to connect until you do that.

Comment: Ok then yo mean tat i should call the receive method before i call the send methos know ? but wen i call the receive method am getting this exception   "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never seem to be calling your `receive` method. If your application never starts listening, no one will ever be able to connect. If you've tried that, and is getting an exception, post that and we'll go from there.

Comment: wen i call the receive method am getting this exception "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

Comment: That could be caused by a number of things - another program listening on the same port, firewall settings, antivirus software.

Comment: This is working fine.But why am i not getting for my IPAddress "192.168.15.41" ?

Comment: You're saying it's working for 127.0.0.1 but not 192.168.15.41? Firewall or antivirus I'd say. For the other issue, put a breakpoint right at the beginning of `OnClientConnect` and see if the code ever gets there.

Comment: As i already said am getting the user's IPAddress by calling the getIP() in my code.As yo say the alternate IPADdress how wil i get it ?   And the control doesnt go to the OnClientConnect  method

Comment: Not really following you there. 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, it will always loop back to your own computer.

Comment: OOps.Sorry its going there.Thank yo so much for your guidance Chris

Comment: So how can i find the User's IPAddress ?

Comment: I'd say that you should first focus on getting it working on your machine.

Comment: i faced a new problem now.Can you please help me out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39317/discussion-between-new-to-net-and-chris)